# CalendarExtender CultureInfo differs from default?

Tags: asp.net

I use AjaxControlToolkit's *CalendarExtender*. I have a *Textbox*, an *ImageButton*, and the *CalendarExtender*. In *web.config* I have

```
<globalization culture="da-DK" uiCulture="da-DK" />
```

At code behind I set the initial date in no postback branch:

```
tbStartDate.Text = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).ToShortDateString();
```

The CalendarExtender's Format property is set for "d" as default.

On the page in *tbStartDate* I get **13-02-2014**. If I choose something in *CalendarExtender* panel, I get **2/14/2015** !?

How and what should I set for the same date format?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What format do you want? You could use `Format="dd-MM-yyyy"` on the `CalendarExtender`.

Not tested but this should work if you always want to use the current culture's format:

```
protected void Page_Init(Object sender)
{
   CalendarExtender1.Format = System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.ShortDatePattern;
}
```